# How to return a very small number as a floatval() yet not as a scientific notation and not using sprintf as it returns a string

Tags: php

## Summary

### Problem

very small float returns either as string or as scientific notation.

### Expected

very small float will return as a number.

### More Info

I have a very small number that I fetch from my db.

`$smallNumber = 0.0000006`, this number naturally returns as a string.

if I use `floatval()`, i'll receive it as a scientific notated number = `6e-7`

to turn it into a real float I normally use `sprintf()` but sprintf returns it back to a string format.

Comment: `6e-7` is a [float](https://3v4l.org/LvRrV), not a string. Try [adding 1](https://3v4l.org/IMl1V) for instance.

Comment: This looks like an XY problem. Whether you see 0.0000006 or 6e-7 **on screen** doesn't change that what's in memory is the same IEEE 744 floating point number (which looks like neither 0.0000006 nor 6e-7). This is purely a presentational aspect.

Comment: Can you please explain what you are trying to achieve here? _“but sprintf returns it back to a string format”_ - and? That should be enough for _display_ purposes; and for any other purpose, it doesn’t matter anyway.